# Modal state with react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm managing Todo lists in my app. The main view is a page with all the lists displayed as cards. If you click on one of them, you can modify, update, delete stuff through a modal that appears.

I have a TodoLists reducer that store all the TodoLists. I don't know how to handle the modal. Should I use redux or just local state?

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { listsActions } from "../duck";

import NewList from "./NewList";
import Card from "./Card";
import Modal from "./Modal";

class Lists extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modal: false,
      list: {}
    };

    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
    this.renderModal = this.renderModal.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchByUserId, user } = this.props;
    if (user !== undefined) {
      fetchByUserId(user.id);
    }
  }

  hideModal() {
    this.setState({
      modal: false
    });
  }

  renderModal() {
    this.setState({
      modal: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    const { modal, list } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <NewProject />
        <div className="columns">
          {_.map(items, (l) => (
            <div
              key={l.id}
              className="column"
            >
              <Card
                list={l}
                onClick={() => this.renderModal(l)}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <Modal
          className={modal ? "is-active" : ""}
          list={list}
          onClose={this.hideModal}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { user } = state.authentication;
  const { items, loading, error } = state.lists;
  return {
    user,
    items,
    loading,
    error
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchByUserId: listsActions.fetchByUserId }
)(Projects);
```

Comment: That can be managed on component level no need to go for state management library

Comment: Say for eg. you want to edit the card and when click on edit a modal opens up with relative fields with values so while generating cards you pass an id to the card event handler function so with that you will make an api call to backend which will fetch you the details of particular card id. You no need to store this data in reducer, it’s just that you dispatch success response and in event handler function you use .then and set the values to the fields which will show in modal